# Audit Log not generating DML statement logs for Cloud-SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to display audit logs for Cloud-SQL in the stack-driver-console. I have already enabled audit-log for Cloud-SQL in IAM.

[image]

I connect to **mysql** or **postgres** databases in Cloud-SQL and when I connect these audit logs are displayed in the console.

[image]

```
  request: {
   @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlInstancesGetRequest"    
   instance: "testpostgres"
```

But after this if I perform any operation in that particular database like **SELECT** or **INSERT** or **DELETE**, there is no audit-log (data-access) generated for both **mysql** and **postgres**. In mysql instance I have set the following database flags:

```
audit_log ON (this is in beta version)
```

For **mysql** if I add 1 more flag `**general_log**` I am able to get those DML statements but they come under a different log `**cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-general.log**` and don't come under **audit-logs**

Similarly for postgres these statements come under a different log:

```
**cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fpostgres.log**
```

I am new to this Cloud-SQL so not aware of the logging implemented there. Why no audit logs are generated when any DML is done for the particular database in that Cloud-SQL instance and should I set any other flag for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DML are not logged on the audit logs by default on Cloud SQL. To see the DML logs in Logging, you need use [pgAudit on your PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit). By the way **pgAudit is only available in PostgreSQL** instances.

**Steps to enable pgaudit:**

1. Enable pgaudit using gcloud command

   `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags \ cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on,pgaudit.log=all`
2. Create the pgaudit extension in your postgres database

   `CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;`
3. Run a simple select statement on your postgres database

**Query DML statements logs in Logging:**

1. Open Logging -> Logs Explorer
2. In the query builder apply this filter:

   `resource.type="cloudsql_database" logName="projects/<your-project-name>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" protoPayload.request.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.audit.v1.PgAuditEntry"`

I used the [quickstart for PostgresSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart) for testing.

Query postgre database:

[image]

Filter Logging using the filter above:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent, can we display the duration in the same audit log, as right for that i am adding 1 more flag log_statement_min_duration, 2)your answer as stated,works for postgres, is there any similar feature available for mysql or mssql?

Comment: @user1403505 1.) Yes you can add another flag and if the flag returns a specific information, that should show in the logs. 2.) mysql does not have a similar feature that is managed by google. I suggest that you post another question specific for mysql, that way the community might provide an answer your question.

Comment: The log flag gives the duration but i wanted it display in the same audit logs displayed above. It is currently showing in the postgres logs only. Thanks

Comment: The pgaudit log is working fine, but it does not give the identity of the IAM user in the logs? The Authentication Info object is not displayed here? how to get that object ? Thanks

Comment: @user1403505 IAM related information is not included in pgaudit fields. The only available fields for pgaudit are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit#pgaudit-log-format). It is best to post a new question regarding this, so that the community can share their insights.

Comment: I wonder if we can create a trigger and store these dml logs in a physical table for each table that has cdc activated?